# functools.partial on class method

Tags: python, exception, methods, functools

I'm trying to define some class methods using another more generic class method as follows:

```
class RGB(object):
    def __init__(self, red, blue, green):
        super(RGB, self).__init__()
        self._red = red
        self._blue = blue
        self._green = green

    def _color(self, type):
        return getattr(self, type)

    red = functools.partial(_color, type='_red')
    blue = functools.partial(_color, type='_blue')
    green = functools.partial(_color, type='_green')
```

But when i attempt to invoke any of those methods i get:

```
rgb = RGB(100, 192, 240)
print rgb.red()
TypeError: _color() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I guess self is not passed to `_color` since `rgb.red(rgb)` works.

Comment: This is a useful question, and I don't want to detract from the main point, but as a side-issue question on your code I was wondering why you wrote super(RGB, self).__init__(), when RGB inherits from object?

Comment: @CaptainLepton It's good practice, in case someday somebody adds a superclass.

Comment: @michaelb958--GoFundMonica you meant making `RGB` superclass to a newer written subclass?

Comment: @deadvoid he means if someone edits the line `class RGB(object)` to instead say something like `class RGB(Other class)`, then the `__init__` is still correct. Of course the tradeoff is that `super(RGB, self)` breaks if you instead edit it to `class Other name(object)`. Of course Python 3 fixed that by letting you just call `super()`.

Comment: @CaptainLepton the biggest reason why it's good practice is that it makes your class actually work right if someone wants to multiply inherit from both your class and another class. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310777/4372452).

Comment: Of course, there is a decent argument to be made that Python code is actually better on balance in the cases that warrant multiple inheritance by just naming parent classes directly instead of using `super()` - you can only really reliably use `super()` to call methods *with arguments* if every class in the MRO has the same signature for that method, and any time the signatures are incompatible, it's just *necessary* to invoke them by name. (There is no way to call superclass' methods in a way that passes all arguments through but calls each superclass' method with just its own arguments.)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are creating partials on the *function*, not the method. `functools.partial()` objects are not descriptors, they will not themselves add the `self` argument and cannot act as methods themselves. You can *only* wrap bound methods or functions, they don't work at all with unbound methods. This is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects):

> `partial` objects are like `function` objects in that they are callable, weak referencable, and can have attributes. There are some important differences. For instance, the `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes are not created automatically. Also, `partial` objects defined in classes behave like static methods and do not transform into bound methods during instance attribute look-up.

Use `property`s instead; these *are* descriptors:

```
class RGB(object):
    def __init__(self, red, blue, green):
        super(RGB, self).__init__()
        self._red = red
        self._blue = blue
        self._green = green

    def _color(self, type):
        return getattr(self, type)

    @property
    def red(self): return self._color('_red')
    @property
    def blue(self): return self._color('_blue')
    @property
    def green(self): return self._color('_green')
```

As of Python 3.4, you can use the new [`functools.partialmethod()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) here; it'll do the right thing when bound to an instance:

```
class RGB(object):
    def __init__(self, red, blue, green):
        super(RGB, self).__init__()
        self._red = red
        self._blue = blue
        self._green = green

    def _color(self, type):
        return getattr(self, type)

    red = functools.partialmethod(_color, type='_red')
    blue = functools.partialmethod(_color, type='_blue')
    green = functools.partialmethod(_color, type='_green')
```

but these'd have to be called, whilst the `property` objects can be used as simple attributes.

Comment: What about `self.red = functools.partial(RGB._color, self, 'red')` in `__init__`? It is Python2 compatible too.

Comment: @dashesy: sure, but that puts those objects on each instance (a memory cost), also making it harder for a subclass to replace them.

Comment: It seems to work if I create a partial from the `_color()` method from an instance of `RGB`?

Comment: @VictorCui: then you created a partial for a *bound* method, and it'll remain bound to the specific instance. That's not the same thing as creating a partialmethod that then re-binds `self` to the current instance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is `functools.partialmethod()` creating partial methods that re-binds `self` to the current instance like your code example?

Comment: @VictorCui exactly

Answer (score 8):

The issue with `partialmethod` is that it is not compatible with `inspect.signature`, `functools.wraps`,...

Weirdly enough, if you re-implement `functools.partial` yourself using the [partial documentation implementation example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), it will work:

```py
# Implementation from:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

```
class RGB(object):
    def __init__(self, red, blue, green):
        super(RGB, self).__init__()
        self._red = red
        self._blue = blue
        self._green = green

    def _color(self, type):
        return getattr(self, type)

    red = partial(_color, type='_red')
    blue = partial(_color, type='_blue')
    green = partial(_color, type='_green')

rgb = RGB(100, 192, 240)
print(rgb.red())  # Print red
```

The reason is that `newfunc` is a true function which implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) with `newfunc.__get__`. While `type(functools.partial)` is a custom class with `__call__` overwritten. Class won't add the `self` parameter automatically.

Comment: lmao nice find, that means functools.partial kinda breaks the zen of python lol. if it just respected ducktyping it would all work fine anyways