# Monkey patching with a partial function

Tags: python, partials, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkeypatch a method on `SomeClass` from an imported package:

```
from somepackage import SomeClass

def newmethod(obj, node, **kwargs):
    """ """

SomeClass.oldmethod = newmethod
```

Where `obj` and `node` are in the default call signature of `SomeClass.oldmethod`:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def oldmethod(obj, node):
        """ """
```

I'm aware that monkeypatching is not good practice, but we need a workaround while we fix some issues that otherwise can't be tackled.  The above approach works FINE, but we'd like to use partial functions to do this.  For example:

```
from functools import partial
newmethod_a = partial(newmethod, foo='a')
newmethod_b = partial(newmethod, foo='b')
```

The partial function is being called because we need to pass different **kwargs.  But when I try to overload now:

```
SomeClass.oldmethod = newmethod_a
```

I get an error related to the number of arguments passed, but it's very specific to my problem so pasting it might not be helpful...  The error I think is related to the call signature of `oldmethod` taking two positional arguments (`obj, node`), and my partial functions aren't passing a reference to the `obj` and `node` correctly.  I've tried different constructions like:

```
newmethod_a = partial(SomeClass.newmethod, foo='a')
```

I'm sorry that I can't produce a minimal working example.  I hoped maybe an expert would just recognize this issue from experience and tell me if what I'm attempting is even possible within the scope of `partial`.

Thanks

Comment: please state at least the text of the error you are getting, then will be clear whether @Philips answer points in the right direction, or there is something else to it. The possibilities are endless...

Comment: Your question is really a duplicate of [functools.partial on class method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16626789); I'll let you pay out the bounty for now.

Comment: I asked this question 4 months ago, I don't really have the environment anymore to test the solution.  The answer provided seems nice though.  I didn't put the bounty up though

Comment: @MartijnPieters It was my bounty. I didn't find the functools.partial on a classmethod question but it looks relevant, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, funnily enough, this question is actually older than that question, though it didn't have any answers until today!

Comment: @RickTeachey: that question is two years old, yours only a few months. :-) I added in the `partialmethod()` info into my answer there when I recalled I had posted it and that it could benefit from the extra info, back in March this year.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters haha whoops!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
from functools import partial

class foo(object):
    def bar(self, pos1, **kwargs):
        print("bar got self=%r, pos1=%r, kwargs=%r" % (self, pos1, kwargs))

foo.bar = partial(foo.bar, qux=1)
baz = foo()
baz.bar(1) # Fails...
```

This fails with a `TypeError`. The reason for this is that `baz.bar` is a bound method which expects its first argument to be a `foo` instance, but that the `partial` object is not, and hence Python will not add `self` for you when you call `baz.bar`. (This is not entirely correct, but the true reason is quite technical. See the Descriptor How-To linked below.)  Calling `baz.bar(baz, 1)` would work. To work around this, you'll have to make `foo.bar` a method again:

```
import types

# In Python 2:
foo.bar = types.MethodType(partial(foo.bar.__func__, qux=1), None, foo)
# Method that is compatible with both Python 2 and 3:
foo.bar = types.MethodType(partial(foo.bar, qux=1), foo)
# Python 3 only:
from functools import partialmethod
foo.bar = partialmethod(foo.bar, qux=1)

baz = foo()
baz.bar(1) # Works!
```

See also:

- Closely related: [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object), [functools.partial on class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626789/functools-partial-on-class-method)
- Loosely related, on functions vs. methods and when/how methods are bound:

  - [Documentation on Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)
  - [How-To guide for descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm)
  - [Bind an unbound method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method)

Comment: In Python 3, use [`functools.partialmethod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod); it is specifically designed for this usecase.

Comment: Thanks, I added that and a link to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
newmethod_a = functools.partial(newmethod, foo='a')
```

with:

```
def newmethod_a(obj, node, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update({"foo": "a"})
    return newmethod(obj, node, **kwargs)
```